# System running in low graphic mode (Ubuntu without monitor)

Tags: monitor, system, headless

I have Ubuntu desktop 12.10. I want to have a desktop server but it can't start without a monitor. I tried Ubuntu server but I got the same error. Everything is working fine while monitor is connected, but when I disable the monitor and reboot the PC, Ubuntu does not start. It says "System in running in low graphic mode". Please tell me a solution for this.

Any app that will "simulate" monitor for remote controlling.

Thanks...